# cv2.createStitcher() not enough keypoints?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on a project to have multiple cameras, each taking an image and then the images will be stitched together. Currently I am trying to use the `cv2.createStitcher().stitch(images)` function. Below is the code that I use:

```
import cv2

imageFiles = ['imageCapture1_0.png','imageCapture2_0.png']
images = []
for filename in imageFiles:
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    images.append(img)

cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)
stitcher = cv2.createStitcher()
status, result = stitcher.stitch(images)             

cv2.imwrite('result.png',result)
```

The image input is:

left image:

[image: left image]

right image:

[image: right image]

However, result output type becomes NoneType with size 1 and value: NoneType object of builtins modules. From what I have googled, the cause of this is because there is not enough matching keypoint to stitch the images together. If so, is there a way to stitch image even with less keypoint? Is there a way to set the parameter? I read through the documentation with no luck trying to find the solution. Thank you in advance

Comment: what does `status` return in your case?

Comment: status, type int, size 1, value 1

Comment: since it is returning 1 you need to add more images. If that is not what you want then good ahead a try building your own stitching module by incorporating feature points and matching them.

Comment: I followed a blog post on panorama stitching. Using the images you provided I am getting an inverted image :D. You can also give it a try [HERE](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/11/opencv-panorama-stitching/)

Answer (score 3):

The image stitching operation `status, result = stitcher.stitch(images)` returns two values, a status indicator and the resulting stitched image. You can check the value of `status` to determine whether or not the image stitching operation was a success. From the docs it can be one of four variables:

`OK = 0`: Image stitching was successful.

`ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS = 1`: There were not enough keypoints detected in your input images to construct the panorama. You will need more input images.

`ERR_HOMOGRAPHY_EST_FAIL = 2`: This error occurs when the RANSAC homography estimation fails. Similarly, you may need more input images or the images provided do not have enough distinguishing features for keypoints to be accurately matched.

`ERR_CAMERA_PARAMS_ADJUST_FAIL = 3`: Usually related to failing to properly estimate camera features from the input images.

For your situation, you can either add more input images so there will be enough keypoints detected or you can look into your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and run your code. It is working all fine.

[Left Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5msa.jpg)

[Right Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIj4J.jpg)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVCcA.jpg)

What I think is that the function could not find the enough match points in your pictures. Trying this code for another set of pictures may help.